# Stuck doing multiple linear regression with python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, regression

I have the following feature vector [Y, x1, x2, x3, x4, ... , x31, x32, x33]
I've created a dataset about 100 rows/34 columns of data
(I want to predict blood sugar given nutritional info of a meal taken in as well as the patient's age, weight, diabetes medication if any, etc...)

```
X = dataset.drop(columns="Y")
y = dataset["Y"]
X_train,X_test, y_train, y_test= train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.2,random_state=0)
```

and I am just unsure of where to go from here. I've seen a lot of videos and read a lot of blogs but it just got me confused and I'm not sure if multiple linear regression will actually work

Any guidance will be appreciated :)

Comment: You want to write code yourself for educational purposes, or are you only interested in final solution?

Comment: I want to write it myself but I just need some help with what regression model to use, I tried to implement using examples as reference but I kept getting too many errors

Comment: [Here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/simple-linear-regression-tutorial-for-machine-learning/) is a quick tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are "n" things that you can do from here. You can find sample code from anywhere on the internet but here are the things that I would suggest you do.
I am not sure if you want to build a linear regression model or use an existing multiple linear regression model to analyze the data. I am assuming later. From here you can

1. Identify Multi Collinearity in the Input Data
2. Create a Multiple Linear Regression Model with all the parameters and identify what's the Adjusted R-Squared value.
3. Identify the significance of regression variables using t-Test
4. Standardize Regression Coefficients using Unit Normal scaling and identify which variable has significance on the output.

As you are beginner, I suggest you pick few random variables and create a linear regression model without worrying about the model efficiency. You can follow any available source on internet to do this task. Google sklearn multiple linear regression for finding exampels on internet.